# Why can't some integral be"found" though they are anti-derivative & exist?

Tags: integration, intuition

In my book, a list of integrals have been given which the author states

> ... such anti-derivatives "cannot be found".

Some of the members of the list are as under:

> $\int\dfrac{\sin x}{x} dx$ , $\int\dfrac{1}{\log x} dx$, $\int\sqrt{1 - k^2\sin^2x}dx$, $\int\sqrt{\sin x}dx$, $\int\cos(x^2) dx$, $\int x\tan xdx$ , $\int e^{-x^2}dx$, $\int\dfrac{x^2}{1 +x ^5}dx$, $\int\sqrt{1 + x^3}dx$.

The author only mentions that:

> ...not every anti-derivatives, even when **it exists**, is expressed in **closed form** ....

Now, can anyone tell me why these integrals "cannot be found"? Are they discontinous, non-differentiable or what? Also, what did the author mean by **closed form**??

Comment: If it's an anti-derivative, it sure better be differentiable...  "Closed form" usually means in this context, "Can be written as a combination of elementary functions, e.g. ones of the form $\sin,\cos,\tan,\exp,\log$, constants, polynomials, etc"

Comment: Are you sure $\int\frac{x^2}{1+x^5}dx$ is on that list?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Oh! Yes sir! It is included & on your saying I've rechecked again & it is included but don't know why it is included.

Comment: Seems like a typo.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Can you tell, why, sir?

Comment: It has a closed-form antiderivative. (Wolfram Alpha can compute it for you.) Perhaps he meant something like $\int\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^5}}dx$, which does not have an elementary solution.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Thanks sir, for amendment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that a function is simply a rule for turning an input into an output. This means that:
$$f(x)=\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$$
is a perfectly fine function. The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that $f(x)$ is an antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$.

However, $f(x)$ cannot be written in *closed-form*. What that means, in this context, is that $f(x)$ cannot be written as some combination of polynomials, trig functions, exponents, logarithms, additions, subtractions, multiplications, and divisions. (A function that *can* be written in such a form is usually called an *elementary function*. $e^{-x^2}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative.)

The proof that $e^{-x^2}$ has no elementary antiderivative is extremely difficult.

Comment: +1; Okay, sir, this is new to me; I just wanted to ask you what the proof is but your last line nailed my hopes! Still, I would ask you to atleast provide me a source or a link that deduces the proof. Also, can you tell what the antiderivative looks like  without any elementary functions?? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: @user36790 See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) for a discussion of that particular integral.

Comment: @user36790 To prove it, you need to know a branch of math called "differential Galois theory," which I know nothing about. I've heard that you can prove this from Liouville's theorem and the Risch algorithm, but I never found a good introduction to the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the resource; since it is beyond my scope now to understand the theorems Lucian linked, I want to ask you how can I detect this integral can't have anti-derivative in closed-form?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know a whole lot about this branch of math. I think that the Risch algorithm is a way to see what functions have antiderivatives and what functions don't, but I've never looked into it.

Answer (score 3):

It means that these antiderivatives exist and are perfectly fine functions, but they can not be expressed by other elementary functions (functions that we are already well familiar with). If such anti derivative comes up very often, it is often given a name. Then you can study its properties and use it like any other function. Such functions are often called "special functions", but there is nothing more special about them than about sine or exponential.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can anyone tell me why these integrals “cannot be found” ?*

For instance, the roots of a $($general$)$ [quintic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Finding_roots_of_a_quintic_equation) cannot be found either, i.e., they cannot be expressed in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). Basically, what the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem) is for polynomials, [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) are for calculus.

Answer (score 0):

*Closed form* means that the integral cannot be expressed in standard mathematical functions like trigonometric, exponential or polynomial functions etc. 
See the example of $\int {{2^2}^2}^x dx$. Also, you may want to study elliptic integrals.