# how to calculate integral of ln(arctan(x))

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck with the following question:

$$\int \ln(\arctan(x))\,\mathrm dx$$

My thoughts were to set $u = \arctan(x) \rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = 1/(1+x^2)$ but I didn't came much further. Anyone that can help me?

Comment: I don't think an elementary antiderivative exists.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397132/why-cant-some-integral-befound-though-they-are-anti-derivative-exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int\ln(\arctan(x))dx$$
if we let: $x=\tan(u)$ then $dx=\sec^2(u)du$ and so:
$$I=\int\ln(u)\sec^2(u)du$$
now by using integration by parts:
$$I=\ln(u)\tan(u)-\int\frac{\tan(u)}{u}du$$
now since:
$$\tan(u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+2}\bigl(2^{2n+2}-1\bigr)B_{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}u^{2n+1}$$
$$\therefore \frac{\tan(u)}{u}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+2}\bigl(2^{2n+2}-1\bigr)B_{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}u^{2n}$$
$$\int\frac{\tan(u)}{u}du=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+2}\bigl(2^{2n+2}-1\bigr)B_{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}u^{2n}du=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+2}\bigl(2^{2n+2}-1\bigr)B_{2n+2}}{(2n+1)(2n+2)!}u^{2n+1}$$
If we bring all this together and back-substitute we should get:
$$I=x\ln(\arctan(x))-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+2}\bigl(2^{2n+2}-1\bigr)B_{2n+2}}{(2n+1)(2n+2)!}(\arctan(x))^{2n+1}+C$$